# Coupling cofficient of coil in Resonant Series RLC Circuit

Tags: passive-networks, series, resonance, mutual-inductance

[image]

In the above diagram the circuit is in Series Resonance. Now we are asked to find the coupling coefficient K between coils L1 and L2. 
For which i first calculated L(equivalent) as follows :

```
Leq = L1 + L2 + 2M ( Dots are in aiding position)
Leq = 12 + 3 + 2M (Assuming w = 1)
Leq = 15 + 2M (M denotes mutual inductance between two coils)
```

So the circuit becomes

[image]

Since The circuit is in resonace the XL should equal to Xc

```
  Xc = XL
-jw18 = jw(15+2M)
 -18  = 15 + 2M ( w = 1)
  -16.5 = M
```

Now, To find coupling coefficient K, we can use the follow formula

```
K = M / sqrt(L1*L2)
K = -16.5/ sqrt(12*3) = -2.75
```

**Which is not possible, Since Range of k should be 0 < K < 1.**
Where am i wrong ? Please Help...

Answer (score 1):

Hint - if the two inductors were perfectly coupled (k = 1) then you would get a total reactance of j27 ohms. Are you able to see that? If you are then clearly, to obtain a total reactance of j18 ohms k must be less than 1.

How did I get j27 ohms - it's a sanity check - reactance or inductance is proportional to turns squared and if coupling is 100% then the turns for L1 and L2 are perfectly coupled and can be regarded as being on the same former so, new impedance is \$j(\sqrt{12} + \sqrt{3})^2\$ = j27 ohms.

I think the mistake I see is that you equate the reactance to -j18 when in fact M should equal j3.

Comment: @MayankPal Did this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here equivalent Inductance is 15+2M but in resonance condition capacitive reactance equal to inductive reactance so here 18=15+2M then M value becomes 1.5 from this K=0.25